# calculating parallel lines in a circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

I am calculating lines (2 sets of coordinates ) ( the purple and green-blue lines ) that are *n* perpendicular distance from an original line. (original line is pink ) ( distance is the green arrow )

How do I get the coordinates of the four new points?

I have the coordinates of the 2 original points and their angles. ( pink line )

I need it to work if the lines are vertical, or any other orientation.

Right now I am trying to calculate it by:
1. get new point n distance perpendicular to the two old points
2. find where the circle intersects the new line I have defined.

I feel like there is an easier way.

Comment: Is this a programming or a math question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to @MBo's answer, let's assume that the center is `(0,0)` and that your initial two points are:

```
P0 = (x0, y0) and P1 = (x1, y1)
```

A point on the line `P0P1` has the form:

```
(x, y) = c(x1 - x0, y1 - y0) + (x0, y0)
```

for some constant `c`.

Let `(u, v)` be the normal to the line `P0P1`:

```
(u, v) = (y1 - y0, x1 - x0) / sqrt((x1 - x0)^2 + (y1 - y0)^2)
```

A point on any of the lines parallel to `P0P1` has the form:

```
(x, y) = c(x1 - x0, y1 - y0) + (x0, y0) +/- (u, v)* n         {eq 1}
```

where `n` is the perpendicular distance between lines and `c` is a constant.

What remains here is to find the values of `c` such that `(x,y)` is on the circle. But these can be calculated by solving the following two quadratic equations:

```
(c(x1 - x0) + x0 +/- u*n)^2 + (c(y1 - y0) + y0 +/- v*n)^2 = r^2
```

where `r` is the radius. Note that these equations can be written as:

```
c^2(x1 - x0)^2 + 2c(x1 - x0)*(x0 +/- u*n) + (x0 +/- u*n)^2
 + c^2(y1 - y0)^2 + 2c(y1 - y0)*(y0 +/- v*n) + (y0 +/- v*n)^2 = r^2
```

or

```
A*c^2 + B*c + D = 0
```

where

```
A = (x1 - x0)^2 + (y1 - y0)^2
B = 2(x1 - x0)*(x0 +/- u*n) + 2(y1 - y0)*(y0 +/- v*n)
D = (x0 +/- u*n)^2 + (y0 +/- v*n)^2 - r^2
```

which are actually two quadratic equations one for each selection of the +/- signs. The 4 solutions of these two equations will give you the four values of `c` from which you will get the four points using {eq 1}

---

**UPDATE**

Here are the two quadratic equations (I've reused the letters `A`, `B` and `C` but they are different in each case):

```
A*c^2 + B*c + D = 0                                           {eq 2}
```

where

```
A = (x1 - x0)^2 + (y1 - y0)^2
B = 2(x1 - x0)*(x0 + u*n) + 2(y1 - y0)*(y0 + v*n)
D = (x0 + u*n)^2 + (y0 + v*n)^2 - r^2
```

---

```
A*c^2 + B*c + D = 0                                           {eq 3}
```

where

```
A = (x1 - x0)^2 + (y1 - y0)^2
B = 2(x1 - x0)*(x0 - u*n) + 2(y1 - y0)*(y0 - v*n)
D = (x0 - u*n)^2 + (y0 - v*n)^2 - r^2
```

Comment: thanks for your thorough answer. In terms of the formatting of your answer: is (x,y) mean that every x value corresponds to the 1st thing before the comma?  Also, is there a difference between c and C in your equations? Also, what is the code equivalent to deal with +/- ? is it a conditional to check n >= 0 ?

Comment: Also, what is D in your 2nd to last equation?

Comment: Please note that I've modified the very last line so that now it defines `D`, the independent term in the quadratic equation `A*c^2 + B*c + D = 0`.

Comment: Yes, the the notation `(x,y)` means that everything before the comma corresponds to `x` and everything after the comma to `y`. This is the standard notation of ordered pairs.

Comment: thanks!^^ Also, how does the quadratic equation produce 4 values? I assume that it has to do with the arrangement of the +/- signs?

Comment: And is there a correspondence between the +/- signs on the {eq 1} and the ones in the quadratic eq? i.e., when computing each of the 4 values, do the values of the signs in the quadratic correspond in some way to the ones in {eq 1}?

Comment: There are two quadratic equations. One with +, the other with -. I've written them in a condensed way using +/-. And since each quadratic equation has two solutions, you will obtain 4 solutions, corresponding to the 4 points you are looking for.

Comment: do the +/- signs in {eq 1} correspond to the sign that produces the solution to the equation? i.e. the sign that produces one of the 2 solutions to the equation? Or does it correspond to the signs that produce the coefficients?

Comment: @awongh See the **UPDATE** at the end (is it clearer now?)

Answer (score 0):

Let's circle radius is R, circle center is `(0,0)` (if not, shift all coordinates to simplify math), first chord end is `P0=(x0, y0)`, second chord end is `P1=(x1,y1)`, unknown new chord end is `P=(x,y)`.
Chord length L is

```
L = Sqrt((x1-x0)^2 + (y1-y0)^2)
```

Chord ends lie on the circle, so

```
x^2 + y^2 = R^2   {1}
```

Doubled area of triangle PP0P1 might be expressed as product of the base and height and through absolute value of cross product of two edge vectors, so

```
+/- L * n = (x-x0)*(y-y1)-(x-x1)*(y-y0) =   {2}
        x*y - x*y1 - x0*y + x0*y1 - x*y + x*y0 + x1*y - x1*y0 = 
        x * (y0-y1) + y * (x1-x0) + (x0*y1-x1*y0)
```

Solve system of equation {1} and {2}, find coordinates of new chord ends.
(Up to 4 points - two for `+L*n` case, two for `-L*n` case)

I cannot claim though that this method is simpler - {2} is essentially an equation of parallel line, and substitution in {1} is intersection with circle.